# How to design a bit-addressable memory?

Tags: architecture, riscv

I am designing a RISC architecture single-cycle diagram. For instance, I have 16 bits of data:

```
  1101101001100010
```

and I wish to access the instruction at index 0, I should get the first 4 bits.

```
  1101101001100010
  ^^^^
```

But I wish to access the instruction at index 3, I should get 4 bits after skipping the first 3 bits.

```
  1101101001100010
     ^^^^
```

My architecture currently looks like the following:

[image: instruction memory architecture diagram]

Here, every 4 bits is treated like a block, but I need to make this continuous like the example explained above. **How should I design this in order to get the a bit at a particular address followed by the next 3 bits in the system?**

Answer (score 1):

Handling variable length instructions will take real work, which is one reason why many RISC architectures initially avoid it.

I would guess that you'll need some shift capabilities, up to the maximum number of bits in an instruction.

I would create an instruction stream buffer, say 16 bits (or more).  Also a counter of how many valid instruction bits are in the buffer (initially zero).

Whenever the bit counter goes less than, say, 8 bits, then load 8 more bits from memory into the buffer so that there are always at least 8 bits in the instruction stream buffer.  These new instruction bits will have to be shifted into proper position and then or'd into the instruction stream buffer.

The bits of interest are at one end of the instruction stream buffer.  When you consume 4 bits, then shift the instruction stream buffer by 4 bits, while also decrementing the bit counter by 4, or if you consume 3 bits then shift by 3 while decrementing the bit counter by 3.

You'll need special handling for jump/branch instructions if you allow jumping to any bit position — you'll have to restart the instruction stream buffer, and skip over some bits to get to an arbitrary bit position.  (Lots of room for optimization here if you expect very short branches, i.e. small loops or if-then/if-then-else.)

Comment: Your method seems to be a good answer. But as I thought and you explained, it is a difficult idea to implement. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It will be work to implement but it should work with existing designs like shifters, comparators, and existing (e.g. byte addressable) memory designs.  I'm curious if anyone has a better/simpler idea?